# how to SetDeadline on DialTCP function and handle timeout error

Tags: go

I am creating a TCP connection to a server but I need to specify a timeout.

How can I achieve such a thing?

This is the simplified code:

```
tcpserveraddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", Serveraddr+":"+Serverport)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("error during address relolution: %v\n", err)
}
serversocket, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpserveraddr)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("error during serversocket.DialTCP(): %v\n", err)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward option is to use [`net.DialTimeout()`](https://godoc.org/net#DialTimeout):

```
net.DialTimeout(tcpserveraddr.Network(), tcpserveraddr.String(), 5*time.Second)
```

What you can also do is create a [`net.Dialer`](https://godoc.org/net#Dialer), which gives you more control over the dialing options, and then use [`DialContext()`](https://godoc.org/net#Dialer.DialContext) with your own context (with timeout):

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
defer cancel()
var d net.Dialer
d.DialContext(ctx, tcpserveraddr.Network(), tcpserveraddr.String())
```